# Image upload not working on server (but working on local) in Laravel. Images not passed to controller

Tags: php, laravel-6

I'm having issues with an image uploading form in Laravel.
On my localhost everything is working fine, but when i push to a server the images don't get passed to the controller. 
The form has the `enctype="multipart/form-data"`
This is my form-field for the upload

```
<div class="form-group">
    <div class="col">
        <label for="photos">Add images here</label>
        <input multiple="multiple" type="file" name="photos[]" class="form-control">
    </div>
</div>
```

When is submit the form and put `dd($request);`at the beginning of my controller, I get these responses:

Local:

```
+files: Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\FileBag {#57 ▼
    #parameters: array:1 [▼
      "photos" => array:1 [▼
        0 => Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\File\UploadedFile {#42 ▼
          -test: false
          -originalName: "photo.jpg"
          -mimeType: "image/jpeg"
          -error: 0
          path: "/private/var/tmp"
          filename: "phpdwAuus"
          basename: "phpdwAuus"
          pathname: "/private/var/tmp/phpdwAuus"
          extension: ""
          realPath: "/private/var/tmp/phpdwAuus"
          aTime: 2020-01-06 13:43:53
          mTime: 2020-01-06 13:43:53
          cTime: 2020-01-06 13:43:53
          inode: 8623609813
          size: 3142496
          perms: 0100600
          owner: 501
          group: 0
          type: "file"
          writable: true
          readable: true
          executable: false
          file: true
          dir: false
          link: false
        }
      ]
    ]
  }
```

Server:

```
+files: Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\FileBag {#56 ▼
    #parameters: []
  }
```

The other fields get returned, and end up in the db. 
This problem is the same for the create and edit table

Comment: In which path you are trying to store youe image? have you checked the permission of that folder into your server?

Comment: In my local the img is stored at storage>app>public>photos. I also did chmod 777 for this folder on the server. But I guess the img doesn't reach the controller so this shouldn't matter?

Comment: delete cache and check the source code of the form generated by laravel on your page

Comment: Also, check the error logs. They should have some really useful information in them.

Comment: Ok, deleted the cache, and inspected the form. there seems to be nothing wrong.

Comment: @JayBlanchard The logs in laravel don't show anything strange... I also added ```\Log::info($request->photos)```to the controller and returns ```[2020-01-06 16:19:42] local.INFO:```